# Wordpress Invalid argument

Tags: php, wordpress

"Warning: : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ..\Menu\Menu.php on line 363 in a site.  It reads as follows.

```
foreach($results['result'] as $result)
        {
            $thumbnail = apply_filters('jnews_image_lazy_owl', $result->ID, 'jnews-360x180');
            $additional_class = (!has_post_thumbnail( $result->ID )) ? 'no_thumbnail' : '';

            $article_output .=
                "<div class=\"jeg_newsfeed_item {$additional_class}\">
                    <div class=\"jeg_thumb\">
                        " . jnews_edit_post( $result->ID ) . "
                        <a href=\"" . get_the_permalink($result) . "\">" . $thumbnail . "</a>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class=\"jeg_post_title\"><a href=\"" . get_the_permalink($result) . "\">" . get_the_title($result) . "</a></h3>
                </div>";

        }


        return $article_output;
```

Comment: Looks like `$results['result']` isn't an array. `var_dump($results['result']);` to see what it contains.

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the value for $results? That's most likely where your problem is.

Comment: code : https://shrib.com/#E9LNm9fVEZsBgSVrp9y8

Comment: file  : https://ufile.io/pqi53 
Error menu File at line 363 :  https://ufile.io/zat63

Comment: There still isn't enough code here to be going with. The call to the code in the shrib.com link is still missing. You are going to have to debug by placing var_dump($result); and var_dump($results); in various places throughout the code until you trace the point at which $results doesn't contain what is expected.

It could be as simple as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should to use $results instead of $results['result'].
If it will not work try this:

```
foreach((array) $results['result'] as $kay => $result)
{
    ...
}
```